# How do I turn my input text file into individual variables? Java

Tags: java

I need help with a small mars lander video-game I'm making for my computer science class. We have to read a game config text file using scanner and use it as the rules for the different aspects of our game (Gravity, amount of fuel you have, etc.) She gave us different text files and they all have different difficulties and values, but they all have the same format, so I need to be able to simply call the different text file and have a new level ready to play. My question is:

How do I get the input from the file into separate variables so that I can manipulate them to create the game?

Here's the code for reading the text file, it also prints it out to the console

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MarsLander {
public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("gameConfig.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNext()){
                String s = sc.next();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to open file!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is one of the text game config files:

```
1000 500
mars_sky.jpg
ship.png ship_bottom.png ship_left.png ship_right.png ship_landed.png ship_crashed.png
20 50
500.0 400.0
100
thrust.wav yay.wav explosion.wav
-0.1
2.0
0.5
500 50
```

Comment: If they are always in the same format and always the same length. You wouldn't need a loop but rather each `sc.next()` would be a different variable. Be sure to remember to use the correct next for the varaible type.

Comment: Ah, that's all I needed to know, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be turning these properties from a config file into variables, instead use [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that allows you to store these values and refer to them later on like: `config.get("some_key")`

Comment: As a general rule, you should make your questions as specific as possible, otherwise it will look like a "please do my homework for me" question.

Comment: you can use eg. properties file as a config files- look over there https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/
alternatively you can use some config class, with methods `getEasyConfig()` `getHardConfig()` etc. , than to have name of the config properties eg. in enum, and in config you can to return map with that parameters, or anything :)

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I was thinking about something slightly more generic. Let me first show you the piece of code I wrote. I will then explain its behaviour and particularities.

```
public class GameExample {

    private static class Game {
        private Long x, y;

        private List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

        private Game(final Long x, final Long y, final List<String> images) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            this.images = images;
        }

        public Long getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public Long getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public List<String> getImages() {
            return images;
        }

        public static class Builder {
            // Parsing methods used by the builder to read the files and build the configuration
            // TODO: add here builder methods for each line of the file
            private final List<BiFunction<String, Game.Builder, Game.Builder>> parsingMethods = Arrays.asList(
                (str, builder) -> builder.withPositions(str),
                (str, builder) -> builder.withImages(str));

            private Long x, y;

            private List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

            private Builder withPositions(final String str) {
                String[] positions = str.split(" ");
                x = Long.valueOf(positions[0]);
                y = Long.valueOf(positions[1]);

                return this;
            }

            private Builder withImages(final String str) {
                Stream.of(str.split(" ")).forEach(imgStr -> images.add(imgStr));

                return this;
            }

            public Game build(final String filename) throws IOException {
                Scanner sc = null;
                try {
                    // Read the file line by line
                    List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                    // Iterate over each line and call the configured method
                    IntStream.range(0, lines.size()).forEach(
                        index -> parsingMethods.get(index)
                                .apply(lines.get(index), this));

                    // Build an instance of the game
                    return new Game(x, y, images);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    if (sc != null) sc.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Game.Builder builder = new Game.Builder();
        Game game = builder.build("file.txt");

        System.out.println(game.getX() + ":" + game.getY());
        System.out.println(game.getImages());
    }
}
```

This piece of code would output:

**10:15**

**test.jpg**

with a given configuration file containing:

**10 15**

**test.jpg**

Let me explain what was done. We define a Game builder that has only one public method with the signature `Game build(final String filename)`. It takes the filename and will build the game from the content of this file. The cornerstone of this approach is that the builder defines a list that determine which method of the builder is used for each line of the file:

```
private final List<BiFunction<String, Game.Builder, Game.Builder>> parsingMethods = Arrays.asList(
            (str, builder) -> builder.withPositions(str),
            (str, builder) -> builder.withImages(str));
```

This list says:

1. Use the method `withPositions` for the first line
2. Use the method `withImages` for the second line

Now, in the `build` method, it implements the logic that executes the methods on the lines:

```
// Iterate over each line and call the configured method
IntStream.range(0, lines.size()).forEach(
    index -> parsingMethods.get(index)
        .apply(lines.get(index), this));
```

We can therefore easily parse a new line of data by doing the following:

1. Add a new private method in the builder describing how to parse the line;
2. Add this method in the list called `parsingMethods`.